# OpenGL Pseudo-Instanced Rendering shows Black Screen

Tags: c++, opengl

I have some code that loops through a set of objects and renders instances of those objects. The list of objects that needs to be rendered is stored as a `std::map<MeshResource*, std::vector<MeshRendererer*>>`, where an object of class `MeshResource` contains the vertices and indices with the actual data, and an object of class`MeshRenderer` defines the point in space the mesh is to be rendered at.

My rendering code is as follows:

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    for (std::map<MeshResource*, std::vector<MeshRenderer*> >::iterator it = renderables.begin(); it != renderables.end(); it++)
    {
        it->first->setupBeforeRendering();
        cout << "<";
        for (unsigned long i =0; i < it->second.size(); i++)
        {
            //Pass in an identity matrix to the vertex shader- used here only for debugging purposes; the real code correctly inputs any matrix.
            uniformizeModelMatrix(Matrix4::IDENTITY);
            /**
             * StartHere fix rendering problem.
             * Ruled out:
             *  Vertex buffers correctly.
             *  Index buffers correctly.
             *  Matrices correct?
             */
            it->first->render();
        }
        it->first->cleanupAfterRendering();
    }

    geometryPassShader->disable();
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

The function in `MeshResource` that handles setting up the uniforms is as follows:

```
void MeshResource::setupBeforeRendering()
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0); // Vertex position
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*) 12); // Vertex normal
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*) 24); // UV layer 0
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*) 32); // Vertex color
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*) 44); //Material index
}
```

The code that renders the object is this:

```
void MeshResource::render()
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, geometry->numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

And the code that cleans up is this:

```
void MeshResource::cleanupAfterRendering()
{
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
}
```

The end result of this is that I get a black screen, although the end of my rendering pipeline after the rendering code (essentially just drawing axes and lines on the screen) works properly, so I'm fairly sure it's not an issue with the passing of uniforms. If, however, I change the code slightly so that the rendering code calls the setup immediately before rendering, like so:

```
void MeshResource::render()
{
    setupBeforeRendering();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, geometry->numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

The program works as desired. I don't want to have to do this, though, as my aim is to set up vertex, material, etc. data once per object type and then render each instance updating only the transformation information.

The `uniformizeModelMatrix` works as follows:

```
void RenderManager::uniformizeModelMatrix(Matrix4 matrix)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, globalMatrixUBOID);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Matrix4), matrix.ptr());
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Comment: Did you cross post or what are those html-remnants?

Comment: @phresnel No, I just accidentally used the code tags I'm familiar with, then accidentally didn't delete them all on my read-through.

Comment: Hmm. The only difference between the working and the non-working version, from the GL's point of view, should be that uniformizeModelMatrix() call. Although I find it unlikely that it is the cause, I would still ask: what GL calls is it issueing?

Comment: @derhass Edited the original post, see above.